# Проверка состояния клавиши

Tags: delphi

Как проверить состояние клавиши?

Comment: GetKeyboardState

Comment: GetKeyState(int) - поконкретнее, вроде, будет?

Comment: Или тоже самое, но Async. 256 байт пересылать ради одной кнопки - по-индусски.

Comment: А поточнее можно, мне нужно узнать нажата ли клавиша!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно также "снять скан" состояния всех клавиш клавиатуры:

```
...
var kb: TKeyBoardState;
begin
GetKeyboardState(kb);
if(kb[VK_LEFT]=1) then
begin
kb[VK_LEFT]:=0;
SetKeyboardState(kb);
showmessage('');
end;
...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if GetKeyState({код клавиши, типо VK_ESCAPE})=0 then
 begin
 {Делаем что надо}
 end;
```